# Ordenação de resultado Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou efetuado a query abaixo, que era ordenada pela data de criação do lote do produto. Com a migração da versão 11 para R12 do Oracle, o campo de criação de lotes passou a ser a data de migração, ou seja, ontem. Como solução, iremos usar o campo `lote`, que contem a data original de criação. Mas o order by ordena como numérico, nao como data. Como poderia no SQL alterar para esse campo ser ordenado como ser fosse data?

SQL:

```
Select
    -- i.item_no Codigo,
    msi.segment1 Codigo,
  -- i.item_desc1 Descricao,
  msi.description Descricao,
    -- l.lot_no,
    mln.lot_number Lote,
  --l.sublot_no,
    mln.parent_lot_number Sublote,
 -- l.lot_desc,
    mln.description Desc_Lote,
 -- l.qc_grade,
    mln.grade_code,
 -- l.expaction_code,
    mln.expiration_action_code,
 -- l.inactive_ind,
    nvl(mln.disable_flag,'1') Ativo, 
 -- l.origination_type,
    mln.origination_type,
 -- l.expaction_date,   
  mln.expiration_action_code,
 -- l.lot_created,
  mln.creation_date Data_Criacao,
 -- l.expire_date,
    mln.expiration_date,
 -- l.retest_date,
  mln.retest_date,
  --  round(sysdate - l.lot_created) Dias,
      round(sysdate - mln.creation_date) Dias,
   -- round(sum(ili.loct_onhand)) qtde
      round(sum(moq.transaction_quantity)) qtde
From  mtl_lot_numbers       mln,
      mtl_system_items      msi,
      mtl_onhand_quantities moq,
      mtl_item_locations    mil

WHERE msi.inventory_item_id = mln.inventory_item_id
      and   msi.organization_id   = mln.organization_id
      and   msi.inventory_item_id = moq.inventory_item_id
      and   msi.organization_id   = moq.organization_id
    --  and   msi.organization_id   = 131 -- SOMENTE PA0
      and   moq.locator_id        = mil.inventory_location_id      
      and   msi.segment1 between '80000' and '99999'    
   -- and   l.lot_id  != 0 -- NAO EXISTE MAIS
   --and    i.item_no >= nvl(CodigoIni,'80000')
   --and    i.item_no <= nvl(CodigoFim,'99999')

group by        msi.segment1,
  msi.description,
    mln.lot_number,
    mln.parent_lot_number,
    mln.description,
    mln.grade_code,
    mln.expiration_action_code,
    nvl(mln.disable_flag,'1'),
    mln.origination_type,
  mln.expiration_action_code,
  mln.creation_date,
    mln.expiration_date,
  mln.retest_date,
      round(sysdate - mln.creation_date)
having  round(sum(moq.transaction_quantity)) > 0
Order by 2 asc,15 asc
```

Resultado atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solução rápida e suja:

- Reordene as posições dos valores intrínsecos da coluna LOTE (dia/mês/ano) para um formato que retorna a ordem correta (ano/mês/dia):

  `ORDER BY SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(LOTE), 5, 4) || 
  SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(LOTE), 3, 2) || 
  SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(LOTE), 1, 2)`

Solução levemente melhor:

- Converta o conteúdo numérico do campo LOTE para o formato `YYYYMMDD`; refatore sua aplicação.

Solução apropriada:

- Converta o conteúdo numérico do campo LOTE para um `DateTime`; refatore sua aplicação.

Comment: Seu order by funcionou exatamente como precisava. Para esse momento de "incêndio" foi fazer desta forma. Futuramente vou alterar para o formato DateTime. Obrigado!

Comment: @Diego não por isso, é sempre um prazer ajudar!

Answer (score 2):

```
order by to_date(mln.lot_number,'YYYYMMDD') , 15 ASC
```

mas eu reveria a solução, melhor trabalhar com datas (type **date**).

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. Seria o ideal, mas como esse eh um campo core da Oracle, nao podemos alterar. E o campo date que tinhamos, creation_date, foi basicamente eliminado na migracao. Provisoriamente, a ideia do OnoSendai, ou ate a sua, vai resolver o problema. Claro que futuramente vou ter que melhorar isso. Obrigado.

Comment: @Diego Um campo não pode ser eliminado em uma migração sem a devida solução alternativa, o que houve com o campo ?

Comment: Na migracao o campo foi sobrescrito com a data da migracao do banco, ou seja, ontem. A Oracle esta verificando, mas pelo que descobrimos nao vai ter solucao, pois a tabela anterior deixou de existir nessa versao, e a nova que recebeu os valores da antiga foi alimentada via  procedure interna deles, que alimenta automaticamente os campos. E a data de criacao dela foi ontem, logo, as datas que tinham nossas foram sobrescritas....